# How to hide accessibility icon?

Tags: 22.04, accessibility

I am using a laptop with Ubuntu 22.04 that has a very small screen, so I've had to activate the "large text" option from the accessibility menu.

However, the accessibility icon now appears at the top right of my screen, and I can't find a way to remove it.

[image]

I've gone to Settings > Accessibility and disabled the option "Always show Accessibility Menu", but that only works if I also disable "large text". Otherwise, the icon is still there.

Comment: That is the default position if you have Large Text selected. It was the same in earlier versions too. I've not tried it but an alternative is to set scaling to 200% see https://kaanlabs.com/ubuntu-set-scaling-factor-to-200-percent/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This has to be achieved using Gnome Shell extensions, e.g "Hide Universal Access".

Comment: Worked perfectly thanks

Answer (score 8):

1. Search for and install `Extension Manager` from Ubuntu Software.
2. Launch `Extension Manager` and use it to install `Just Perfection` extension via 'Browse' tab.
3. Then open settings for `Just Perfection` by navigating back to 'Installed' tab.
4. Finally, turn off 'Accessibility menu' under Visibility tab.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VVQX9.png)

Comment: Just a repeat of the answer already given.

Comment: @David the answer given is one sentence without directions.

Comment: https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/3843/just-perfection/